# Changing a number in an if loop

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Absolute ASP newb here, I know what I want to do just not sure how.
If you can help I'd be very grateful, and might learn something too.

In an existing Cactushop install (v6.041) in the admin files I've found an if loop that lets the first news item have a picture allocated to it. I want the fist and second to have the ability to have a picture assigned.

```
<% if numItemCount = 1 then %>
```

That's the start of the if loop that below it assigns a picture block to news item number 1. I want to change that, so that it also adds it to news item number 2.

I've tried changing the number to "2" but it then only added the image to news item number 2. Also tried "1,2" and got a syntax error.

Comment: This is a serious question? Have you never used operators before? I realise you say you are a *"ASP newb"* but what programming languages have you worked with if you haven't come across the [< *(less than)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign) operator before? 5 minutes reading the [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84).aspx) would give you this information. For future reference [Comparison Operators (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Yes I did start learning PHP a good while ago, but have since moved into a more design role. I've found my answer below, it took two people less than as many minutes to be nice and help me. Easy problems make for easy solutions right? Why didn't you answer the question for free, easy points? Surely that would be the smart thing to do.

Comment: Right and compound the problem? No thanks. Like you say *"it took two people less than as many minutes to be nice and help me."* providing "*easy solutions*" when in fact if they had left the question a lone maybe people like you would realise that this isn't a quick help site. The attitude you show only emphasizes the point for me more. If I was interested in the rep then I probably would have answered but I care far more about producing quality content on SO.

Comment: At least it wasn't a homework... He tried to read and modify an existing source. I helped him for this (and for free, easy points too).

Comment: Quality content? Is this site a content producer, like a magazine or Reddit, or a forum where you can discuss problems, and learn things? I come here for help, and when I have time to try and help others (as limited as I admit my knowledge is, I might be able to help someone). We clearly both have very different ideas of what SO is, so lets agree to disagree because I haven't got time to argue with you all day.

Comment: No your time is more precious then everyone else's which is why a five minute Google search for the VBScript syntax is more work then letting someone find the answer for you.

Comment: Note that an `If` block isn't a "loop". "Loop" implies that its contents will be executed more than once, so it's used to describe `For...next` or `Do [while|until]...Loop` blocks, but not for `If` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to write :

```
<% if numItemCount <= 2 then %>
```

But we need to see a significant code sample to be more sure.

Comment: Spot on, of course it's a mathematical operator. I haven't coded in a good while and it shows! Thank you @Amessihel.

Comment: Wasn't me, I can only assume it was Lankymart.

Comment: You could also use `<% if (numItemCount = 1) or (numItemCount = 2) then %> ` - which is useful if you have two specific conditions rather than a numeric range.

Comment: @John, it was my first proposition, see my comment below Sergio Internicola's answer

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
<% if numItemCount <= 2 then %>
```

In this case, the if content is executed both when numItemCount is 1 and 2.

Comment: I wish I could accept both as answers! But thank you for your help @Sergio Internicola.

Comment: Ehehehe... @Amessiel copied my solution, but his previous one was right as well.

Comment: @SergioInternicola I haven't copied yours... First I wrote `numItemCount = 1 And numItemCount = 2` then realised it's always `> 0` so I wrote `<= 2`. We answered almost simultaneously. Of course I can't prove it. No problem for giving to you my "approval mark".

Comment: @Amessihel: No problem. It isn't a copyright matter... :-)